# SQL Dynamic Pivot Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm not able to group by the code in my dynamic pivot. I need to group by the code area which is defined in ZONE table as shown below. I need to show the distinct code with group by. Some of the code has more than one zone_id, therefore, I need to merge them. I am using SQL 2008.

```
ZONE_ID SITE_ID     ZONE_NAME             CODE
197      103        ADANA CADDE CAM2    M01001
180      103        ADANA CADDE CAM1    M01001
```

[image: Results]

```
Declare @Date1 date = GetDate()


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
drop table #Dates


SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,START_TIME,106) AS [Date]
INTO #Dates
FROM dbo.DIRECTIONAL_METRIC
WHERE CAST(START_TIME as DATE) >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@Date1)-1),@Date1),101)
and CAST(START_TIME as DATE) <= @Date1
AND DATEPART(HOUR,START_TIME) BETWEEN 9 AND 23
order by [Date]

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(convert(varchar,[Date],106)) 
                                   From   #Dates 
                                   Order by 1 For XML Path('')
                                  ),1,1,'') 

Select  @SQL = N'

Declare @Date1 DATE
SELECT @Date1 = GetDate()


SELECT [CODE],' + @SQL + ',[Grand Total Enter],[Grand Total Exit] 
FROM  
(
        SELECT [CODE]
              ,[Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR, START_TIME, 106)
              ,[NUM_TO_ENTER] 
              ,[Grand Total Enter] = (SELECT SUM(NUM_TO_ENTER) FROM DIRECTIONAL_METRIC WHERE Zone_ID=A.Zone_ID AND
                            CAST(START_TIME AS DATE) >='''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@Date1)-1),@Date1),101)+'''AND CAST(START_TIME AS DATE) <='''+cast(@Date1 as varchar(10))+'''
                            AND DATEPART(HOUR,START_TIME)BETWEEN 9 AND 23)
              ,[Grand Total Exit] =(SELECT SUM(NUM_TO_EXIT)  FROM DIRECTIONAL_METRIC Where Zone_ID=A.Zone_ID AND 
                            CAST(START_TIME AS DATE) >='''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@Date1)-1),@Date1),101)+''' AND CAST(START_TIME AS DATE) <='''+cast(@Date1 as varchar(10))+'''
                            AND DATEPART(HOUR,START_TIME)BETWEEN 9 AND 23)

FROM    DIRECTIONAL_METRIC A INNER JOIN ZONE Z ON Z.ZONE_ID = A.ZONE_ID
        WHERE CAST(START_TIME as DATE) >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@Date1)-1),@Date1),101)
        and CAST(START_TIME as DATE) <= @Date1
        AND DATEPART(HOUR,START_TIME)BETWEEN 9 AND 23
        AND Z.CODE IS NOT NULL
) S
PIVOT 
(
    SUM([NUM_TO_ENTER]) FOR 
    [Date] IN (' + @SQL + ') 
) AS Pvt GROUP BY [CODE] '

Exec(@SQL);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I group by the CODE in my dynamic pivot ?

Comment: same way as always surround the code you have with `SELECT ... FROM (current code) AS X GROUP BY X.CODE`

Comment: This is not a something like that actually.

Comment: has to be a different way to put group by dynamic pivot I guess because I am getting an error for the end of group by that I put

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: (5 row(s) affected)
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Column 'DIRECTIONAL_METRIC.START_TIME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in your derivated query. In you selection is not all column which are in derived table. Group by do sql server automaticaly (it's main think of pivot).

Inside of your pivot is select:

```
SELECT 
    [CODE]
    ,[Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR, START_TIME, 106)
    ,[NUM_TO_ENTER] 
    ,[Grand Total Enter] = (select ...)
    ,[Grand Total Exit] = (select ...)
FROM ...
PIVOT (SUM([NUM_TO_ENTER]) FOR [Date] ...
```

And engine in background do this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY CODE, Grand Total Enter, Grand Total Exit
```

You have to remove your Grand Totals from inside qry. You can move it into outer column selection or separate it into qry and create joins.

You can do sumtotals with + operation of your dynamic columns too (01_Jan_2017 + 01_Feb_2017...).

EDITED 2017-01-04 - Try this:

```
SELECT 
    [CODE]
    ,[Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR, START_TIME, 106)
    ,[NUM_TO_ENTER]
FROM ...
PIVOT (SUM([NUM_TO_ENTER]) FOR [Date] ...
```

EDITED 2017-01-05 - To get totals:

```
SELECT 
    [CODE],
    [Grand Total Enter] = (select ...),
    [Grand Total Exit] = (select ...)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [CODE]
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY [CODE]
) codes
```

To get final output join this two datasets together.

Comment: Can you please show me how can I do that? I tried to seperate that but did not work

Comment: This is really important for me , I will be appreciate if you can edit my query to how I can seperate it into qry

Comment: Thanks a lot but I should put grand total enter and grand total exit.. How can I put them seperately?

Comment: I am still gettin error when I am tryting to do that..Is it possible to show this solution in my code?

Comment: In which part? Which error? Post data (several rows) from join DIRECTIONAL_METRICA + ZONE.